# Spring and Quartz error

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I am trying the example from following site

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-quartz-scheduler-example/

I have added `junit` to fix build error but getting the following error...any help is appreciated

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext
    at com.mkyong.common.App.main(App.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Comment: You might have added maven dependencies correctly but are the jars present in the build path when you run the main method. If not create a run configuration and add those jars in class path

Answer (score 0):

Add `spring-context-support.jar` and `spring-context.jar` in your application path and then run application

Comment: added both spring-context and spring context-support in maven and recompiled but no luck<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <!--  spring-context.jar -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: are you deploying these libray within your application lib as well?

Comment: I am doing mvn package and testing it using jar -cp target/nameOfthe Jar.jar classname

Comment: are you using eclipse to run this application? If yes then make sure these libraries are availible while you running test..

Comment: are you including all the necessary library in classpath while running it from CLI? like. ** java -cp xx.jar:yy.jar  yourclass**